# How to verify a root ca certificate is added succesfully, using Bash?

Tags: ssl, openssl, verification, trusted

### Context

After following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate) instructions on how to add a root ca `ca.crt` to Ubuntu, I was wondering how I can verify in Bash whether the root CA is indeed successfully added as trusted.

In particular because browsers, like Firefox, have their own set of trusted CA's, meaning I cannot visit a local url with an ssl certificate signed with the root ca that is added to the system, to verify the root ca recognises it.

### Question

How can one, using bash, verify a root ca named `ca.crt` is added to the trusted list of certificates in Ubuntu, using a self-signed public SSL certificate named `cert.pem`?

Comment: Firefox uses NSS which _on Ubuntu_ should use the shared `ca-certificates` package data which _is_ updated by `update-ca-certificates` and thus should do what you want. If you are having a problem with that, you should ask about it where it is on-topic (not here).